# Flatten data in a spark sql query - Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to fetch unique values of a column in a table and print it along side the other columns such as sum, tablename as shown in the query below. 
The subquery shown below is fetching multiple rows which is valid but in order to put that in a column, I need to flatten it out as a list or text, e.g [1,2,1]. How can I flatten this data out to fit in the same query as shown below. My preferred approach is to use Spark SQL. Please help.

```
    **Subquery**

    (select distinct $field from tablename) 

    **Actual Code** 

    RDDdf.createOrReplaceTempView(“tablename”)

    val x=  RDDdf.schema.fieldNames

    val dfs = x.map(field => spark.sql(s"select 'RDDdf' as TableName, 
   '$field'as column, sum($field) as Sum, (select distinct $field from 
    tablename) from tablename"))

    **Expected output**

    TableName | column  | Sum | UniqueVal
    ----------+---------+-----+----------
    RDDdf     | a       | 4   | 1,2,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built-in function collect_list:

```
select collect_list(value) from (select distinct($field) as value from tablename) as values
```

Be aware, that this will be VERY slow on large datasets

Comment: Thanks T.Gaweda again ! the dataset is going to be huge with millions of rows...any other way to write the same thing ?

Comment: @sabby The problem is that all the data will be collected to one node. There's no other option to do such query. collect_list is good function, just your use-case makes it slow as there's no other option to show all values in one row than collecting on one node

Comment: The problem is when you have many distinct values of field - if you have milions rows, but only few unique values, then there will be no problem with collecting data on one node :)

Comment: I understand T. Gaweda, I'm yet to test it on S3 data though, not sure how the data would look like..we are migrating from Panda's. Appreciate your help again..straight twice in a day :)